# Kafka Streams: Program architecture for handling multiple streams

Tags: apache-kafka, multiprocessing

I am running multiple individual kafka streams. To this end I created a Stream Manager that holds these streams. Below is the SM class in essence.

```
public class StreamManager {

public Map<String, BaseStream> streamMap = new HashMap<String, BaseStream>();
public Map<String, ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<Long, BaseModel>> storeMap = new HashMap<String, ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<Long, BaseModel>>();    

public StreamManager(String bootstrapServer){
    initialize(bootstrapServer);
}

/**
 * initialize streams.  Right now hard coding creation of streams here.
 * @param bootstrapServer
 */
public void initialize(String bootstrapServer){

    Properties s1Props = this.GetStreamingProperties(bootstrapServer, "STREAM_1");
    Properties s2Props = this.GetStreamingProperties(bootstrapServer, "STREAM_1");

    BaseStream s1Stream = new CompositeInfoStream(new KStreamBuilder(), compositeInfoProps);
    BaseStream s2Stream = new ImcInfoStream(new KStreamBuilder(), imcInfoProps);

    streamMap.put(s1Stream.storeName, s1Stream);
    streamMap.put(s2Stream.storeName, s2Stream);

/**
 * Start all streams
 */
public void startStreams(){
    for(BaseStream stream: streamMap.values()){
        stream.start();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    StreamManager mgr = new StreamManager(StreamingConfig.instance().MESSAGE_SERVER);
    StreamManager.startStreamServices(mgr);

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

            } finally {
                mgr.closeStreams();

            }
        }
    });

    int i = 0;
    while(true) {
        if (i++ == 0)
            mgr.logAllStreamStates();

        Thread.sleep(60000);
        if (i == 60) i = 0;
    }       
}
}
```

I initialize and start the streams and then let the process run in a loop. Now what I want is to have more control over individual streams. To start and kill them if need be (for some odd reason my streams go in REBALANCE mode often and don't come back. Currently, if one of the stream goes into REBALANCING I have to kill the entire SM (all streams) and restart. What I would like to do is only restart the individual stream.

I would like to get a sense of how my architecture should be. Does kafka streams provide a mechanism to manage a cluster of streams? Can I use multiprocessing to accomplish this and if so could you guide me to some resources to do so keeping in mind that we use windows for development and linux for deployment

Comment: I notice that you're passing the same string to `GetStreamingProperties`, is this the group.id you're using for the streaming app? Should they be different?

Comment: hmm would they need to be different. I am using the id for one application which has multiple streams. Most streams are listening to individual topics but there are some that listen to the same topic and I haven't noticed any skips in that regard but cannot be sure. Would it be a problem if two streams (under the same group id) listen to the same topic